# Upper bound on the number of elements in part of an infinite set

Tags: combinatorics, convergence-divergence

Let $A$ be an infinite subset of positive integers. Suppose $\lambda$ is the supremum of all real numbers such that, $\sum_{n\in A} \frac{1}{n^{\lambda}} = \infty$  . I wonder if we have $$k^{\lambda} \ge \sum_{k/2<n\le k, n\in A} 1$$

for all sufficiently large $k$'s (namely there exists $K$ such that for all $k>K$, the above inequality holds)

If $\lambda \ge 1$, then the inequality above trivially holds. But I don't know how to address the case $\lambda < 1$. I can't find a counterexample either.

Comment: If $\lambda\gt1$, then $\sum\limits_{n\in A}\frac1{n^\lambda}\lt\infty$, so we are only concerned with $\lambda\le1$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you wrote the question correctly, then $A := \mathbb{N}, \lambda = 1/2$ is a counterexample.

I assume you meant $\sum_{n \in A} n^{-\lambda} < +\infty$. Then it's true. Suppose $k^\lambda < |A\cap[k/2,k]|$ for infinitely many $k$. Then, for such $k$, we have $\sum_{n \in A \\ n \in [k/2,k]} 1/n^\lambda \ge k^\lambda/k^\lambda = 1$. So $\sum_{n \in A} 1/n^\lambda = +\infty$.

Comment: Sorry this is my mistake. I meant $\lambda$ is the supremum of all real numbers such that that infinite sum is infinite (not finite)... Otherwise this is really silly

Comment: @NoOne Then $A := \{\lfloor n^2/\log^2 n \rfloor : n \ge 100\}, \lambda = 1/2$ is a counter-example.